# Symmetry in sculpting

Tags: sculpting

I have a object that looks like this:[image]

But when I change the wiew angle it looks like this:
[image]

How do I make it symmetric from both numpad1 and numpad3 wiew?
(So it looks like st image from both sides (round))
I know that I am pretty bad with explaining.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Radial Simmetry

At the moment you are using only X simmetry. If you would like to sculpt the same thing in multiple directions, you should go for **radial** simmetry.

Just try to increase the number of Z iterations in the Simmetry panel:

[image]

You could also activate both X and Y simmetry to achieve a perfect mirroring on those axis too.