# Can Blender in sculpt mode apply a stroke 360° around an axis?

Tags: axis, sculpt

Can Blender somehow make a ring around the sculpt in the axis i want when i tap a brush on it?

Comment: Sculpt brushes have Radial setting, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107635/symmetry-in-sculpting

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Radial symmetry will allow you to do exactly that, just increase or decrease the number of steps and change the axis to suit your need.